# Url rewriting by htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I got stuck at url rewriting through htaccess at wordpress

Orignal url: https://www.example.com/view-details/?id=121

Note: view-details is page name (slug)

Required url: https://www.{some-text-here}.example.com

What htaccess should i use for getting my Required url?

Comment: Sub-domain.. ?  http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-a-subdomain-name-how-do-i-create-and-delete-one

Comment: https://www.example.{some-text-here}.com ?